# Sorting results based on key from different table

Tags: mysql

In `table1` one of the fields is `member_id`.

In `table2` one of the fields is `member_username` and the `id` field in this table is equal to the `member_id` field in `table2`.

The goal is to display all results from `table1` in ascending alphabetical order based on `member_username` from `table2`.

Basically I need to resolve the `member_id` from `table1` to a `member_username` from `table2` and sort them alphabetically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a join from `table1` to `table2` to pick up the username, then sort on this field. You just need to be wary of a one-to-many relationship, i.e. if a member might have more than one entry in `table2` with the same id you may get more rows than you expect.

```
select *
from table1
left join table2 on table2.id = table1.member_id
order by table2.member_username
```

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand your question, try joining both tables together and sort by `member_username`.

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.member_username
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.member_id = t2.id
ORDER BY t2.member_username ASC;
```

You can leave `t2.member_username` in the `SELECT`-part of the query, I just put it there for reference.